# Show that this linear map has nontrivial kernel

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$f$ is a linear map on a $k$-vector space $M$ with $f^n=0$ for some $n>0$. $k$ is a field.

$k^d$ is $k$-algebra generated by $x_1,\ldots,x_d$ satisfy the relation $x_i x_j + x_j x_i =0$  for all $i,j=1, \ldots, d$.

Show that $\ker(f)$ is non-zero.

Thank you!

Comment: what does k^d have to do with anything?

Comment: let x in k^d, then x = linear combination of x_i, then x-(sum r_ix_i) =0 then f (x-sum)= 0 ... but it does not work.. I do not know how can i use f^n =0 and the condition

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Choose $n$ in the question such that $f^{n-1}$ is not zero, and notice that $f(f^{n-1}(M))=\{0\}$.

Alternatively, prove that in general a composition of injective maps is injective.

Comment: Please , could you explain more? does that mean ker(f)=f^(n-1)[M]??

Comment: @saba: x is in ker(f) if and only if f(x)=0.  If A is a subset of M such that f(A)={0}, meaning that f(x)=0 for all x in A, then every element of A is in ker(f); that is, A is a subset of the kernel.  $$ $$ As for the second suggestion, have you seen that a linear map has kernel {0} if and only if it is injective (one-to-one)?  If so, it suffices to show that f is not injective.  You can do this by contraposition.  If f is an injective map, then so are $f\circ f$, $f\circ f\circ f$, $f\circ f\circ f\circ f$, etc. The zero map is not injective.

Comment: @saba:  If you like the answer (including the additional comment-it would appear so) please accept it by clicking the check mark next to this answer.  It will prevent it from popping up in the future.